# Howto setup Apache Web Server for clustering a Web Service on two Tomcats

Tags: web-services, apache, apache-axis, tomcat7

I'm trying to setup an Apache Web Server, so that it balances requests of a client on two Tomcat servers. For the Web Service I uses Axis2. It is deployed on two Tomcats. When I invoke the Web Service, there is always only one Server answering, although the cluster is established. I used [this](http://jee-bpel-soa.blogspot.de/2009/07/apache-tomcat-clustering-load-balancing.html) tutorial, Axis2 1.6.1, Tomcat 7, Apache Web Server 2.2 and I am running it on a Windows 32 bit system.
How is it possible to balance the client requests on both Tomcats?
It might have something to do with the proxy configuration of the Web Server, but its just a thought.
If you need screenshots or else, please let me know. And sorry for my german accent :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it works now. It was a configuration problem in the axis2.xml file, where I had the wrong IP. now I have the following configuration on every instance:

```
    <!-- The host name or IP address of this member -->
    <parameter name="localMemberHost">127.0.0.1</parameter>
```

Also important is the server.xml file of the Tomcat instances. Here the Shutdown port must be different for each instance:

Instance 1:

```
        <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Instance 2:

```
        <Server port="8015" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

The connector port must be different, too:

Instance 1:

```
        <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Instance 2:

```
        <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
        <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Then I just set these  adjustments in the httpd.conf file of the Apache Webserver like this:

```
        BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:8009 min=1 max=1 route=node1 loadfactor=1
        BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:8010 min=1 max=1 route=node2 loadfactor=1
```

and now my cluster works fine. Sometimes you have to go back some steps to understand whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Usually with load-balancing (clustering) one server will be answering first - which one will be decided by load-balancer (proxy) in it's configuration. Load-balancer (proxy) usually queries all clustered servers until it finds one that is less busy. In order to tests clustered environment you have to simulate (or create) high load or you can "slow down" (or stop completely) one of the servers.

Comment: Ok I tried to stop one server completely and now the second one is still not answering on the request. When I load the wsdl of the Web Service, both servers answer in turn, what can be checked with the balancer manager. So I thik that my Web Service Client just "talks to" one Tomcat Server without even using the Web Server. Right now I don't know which configuration file is wrong. I have set up the httpd.conf (Web Server), both server.xml files (Tomcat) and the axis2.xml files of the Web Service, which are deployed on the tomcats. Does anyone know which one might be the problem?

Comment: If you get WSDL response from both servers I would think that configuration on both servers is correct.
To localise the problem I would swap the two servers (names/IPs) and check if the behaviour changes.
I.e. your original configuration:
proxy -> server1, server2 - rename server1 to server2 and server2 to server1. If you continue getting the response from server1 -> the problem is in the proxy configuration, if you get response from server2 (original server1) -> the problem is your original server2 (that is now server1) configuration.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I swapped the names and IPs and still get response from the same server. So the problem must be the proxy configuration.